# Smush.It Cron How to enable

Tags: cron, crontab

I have just installed a Magento extension for Smush.it and image optimization extension however when I go into the tool, it tells me that

The Magento CRON is not set up. Please set up your Magento CRON for Smush.it to function correctly.

Please can someone advise as to how I can enable cron for this module

Comment: Are you using Cpanel or what?

Answer (score 1):

you did not enable the cronjob for magento itself I think?

The cronjob runs tasks for magento in the background in a defined intervall.

To setup the magento cronjob, you need access to your server (via ssh) or contact your hosting provider.

You need to add the following entry in your crontab to run the magento cronjob every minute:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/magento/root/cron.sh
```

To edit your crontab, you can run the following command:

```
crontab -e -u your-webservers-user
```